# How to check if Item Deleted in a list was the last item (in a EVENT Receiver)

Tags: 2007, list, development, event-handlers

I want to check If deleted item is the Last Item deleted in the List in following method,

```
public override void ItemDeleted(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{ 

}
```

I know I can get web url using  properties.WebUrl and then find list and then items count in it, but is there any better way of doing it ?

If item wasn't the last one then I can go through all List Items to find the List Item that was added nearest to DateTime.Now, but then I Can go through each list item and compare there dates, Does anyone knows any efficient way ?

**EDIT**

I find LastItemModifiedDate property to get last item, so don't need to go through each list item to find the latest added to the list

**EDIT 2**

I said I can get Last Item, but in real I am able to get last Item modified date, so only thing I know is to go through all items to find one I want :S, **I bet there will be a better way**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find if it's the last item I would use:

```
properties.List.ItemCount < 1
```

But to get the last modified item I would consider using a query:

```
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
q.RowLimit=1;
SPListItemCollection results = properties.List.GetItems(q);
//Last item should be the only entry in results. If no entries, then no items in list.
```

Note: I'm not sure about the sort order on the OrderBy - but I think descending will get the latest modified item.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called ID in SPListItem, that property contains the item's 1-based integer ID, which is one greater than the ID of the item that was previously added. If the item is deleted, its ID is not reuse. check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id) in MSDN for further explanation.

Technically to get last item added is to get biggest ID in SPListItem.

Comment: The highest ID is the most recently created item, not necessarily the most recently modified.